# How to do a division with environment variables of a pseudo array within a FOR loop?

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file

I have a constant variable `X[0]=10` and a pseudo array with `Y[0]=20` and `Y[1]=30`. `N` is defined with value `1`.

I want to do an arithmetic operation using these environment variables in a `for` loop:

```
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,%N%) DO  (
    echo !Y[%%i]!
    set /a t[0]= !Y[%%i]! / !X[0]!
    echo !t[0]!
    echo/
)
```

But it doesn't work. There are displayed the messages:

> ```
> Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bit precision
> ECHO command disabled.
> ```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` does not really support arrays of strings. In real the code created by you creates lots of environment variables with the names specified left to the equal sign. You can see that by adding the command `set` below the __FOR__ loop to get output all environment variables. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the output usage help. There is written for the evaluation of an arithmetic expression: "*Any non-numeric strings in the expression are treated as environment variable names whose values are converted to numbers before using them.*"

Comment: So it is possible to use just `set /A t[%%i]= Y[%%i] / X[0]` as the answer written by Stephan demonstrates too. I would use as second command line `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` to define the required execution environment completely and do not depend on Windows defaults or what another process or batch file defines as execution environment on running this batch file. Your batch file requires enabled command extensions and enabled delayed expansion, whereby the latter only for the `echo` commands, but not for the arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(NOTE: this answer answered the question in its original form. The question then changed (see comments below))

Works fine for me after defining the used variables and enabling delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set N=1
set X[0]=10
set Y[0]=20
set Y[1]=30

FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,%N%) DO  (
   echo !Y[%%i]!
   echo t[%%i]= !Y[%%i]! / !X[0]!
   set /a t[%%i]= Y[%%i] / X[0]
   echo !t[%%i]!
   echo/
)
```

Output:

```
20
t[0]= 20 / 10
2

30
t[1]= 30 / 10
3
```

(Note: `set /a` can use variable names without enclosing them with `%` or `!`)